# Cant webscrape all values from a list when using full xpath

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

im pretty sure i know the issue but cant get the syntax right.

My c# webscrapper.
Is grabbing a random list of people from wikipedia.

I used get full xpath to get the data

```
HtmlNode[] nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/section[2]/ul/li[1]/a").ToArray();
```

So i want to get all the results from the list and write there names to file.
I know it has something to do with the [i].
I was recommended to using something along the lines of

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[position()>1 and position()<15]/a[position()>1]
```

Yet i get no results using it. It was not indented for exactly what im doing.
Some how i need to tell it to cycle through all the li elements. Because currently i just get the first result printed to console. even in the for loop.
The for loop works when i search for just an `a` or `li` tag and returns everything. But annoyingly there are too many a tags on the page.

Can you help? Here is the full code. I hope i explained well enough.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

namespace WebScrapper2
{
class Program
{

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        // Where to get data from
        String url = "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_critical_theorists";

        // Create a client object
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        // use get string to create a get request
        // .result will give us a field
        var html = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("HTML: " + html); // This will display all html

        //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]

        // X path //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]
        // Convert to a format
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        Console.WriteLine("DOC: + " + htmlDocument);

        HtmlNode[] nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/section[2]/ul/li[1]/a").ToArray();
        //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[position()>1 and position()<15]/a[position()>1]

        // HtmlNode[] nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li").ToArray();

        foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXX" + item.InnerHtml);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```